# Why does Java ArrayList write the size field in serialization stream explicitly?

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization

As of Java 8, `ArrayList` uses the next `writeObject` and `readObject` methods for serialization:

```
/**
     * Save the state of the <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance to a stream (that
     * is, serialize it).
     *
     * @serialData The length of the array backing the <tt>ArrayList</tt>
     *             instance is emitted (int), followed by all of its elements
     *             (each an <tt>Object</tt>) in the proper order.
     */
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
        throws java.io.IOException{
        // Write out element count, and any hidden stuff
        int expectedModCount = modCount;
        s.defaultWriteObject();

        // Write out size as capacity for behavioural compatibility with clone()
        s.writeInt(size);

        // Write out all elements in the proper order.
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            s.writeObject(elementData[i]);
        }

        if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reconstitute the <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance from a stream (that is,
     * deserialize it).
     */
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
        throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;

        // Read in size, and any hidden stuff
        s.defaultReadObject();

        // Read in capacity
        s.readInt(); // ignored

        if (size > 0) {
            // be like clone(), allocate array based upon size not capacity
            ensureCapacityInternal(size);

            Object[] a = elementData;
            // Read in all elements in the proper order.
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                a[i] = s.readObject();
            }
        }
    }
```

`ArrayList.size` field has only `private` modifier. It is serialized with `out.defaultWriteObject` method. And it is not used in `readObject` method(I mean deserealized value is not used). Why is `size` added to serialization stream the second time with `s.writeInt(size);`? 
I saw, there is a comment like `// Write out size as capacity for behavioural compatibility with clone()`. But I cann't understand for relation between `size`, size  double serialization in `writeObjectMethod` and `clone()`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this sort of thing is for compatibility between versions. The [spec says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.util.ArrayList)

> The length of the array backing the ArrayList instance is emitted (int), followed by all of its elements (each an Object) in the proper order.

Admittedly the spec is usually missing or wrong. In any case it should be read and write compatible with whatever JRE 1.2.0 did.

I've now checked, older versions used this as the capacity. There is no capacity field as the true value can be obtained by `elementData.length` in an instance, but isn't otherwise written to the stream.